# Auditing in Spring Data MongoDB: is Id or Version field required?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

Is it necessary to add an Id or Version field to an entity in order to save it using Spring Data MongoDB if auditing is enabled? I get this exception when the entity does not have an Id or Version field:

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: Cannot determine IsNewStrategy for type
```

I'm enabling auditing through XML configuration. It works when I add an Id field. If this is necessary, is there any way to disable auditing for a specific entity in XML configuration?

Comment: I face the same issue since I updated my project to spring data mongodb version 1.7.0. With release 1.6.2 everything works fine. I opened a ticket regarding this issue: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1212

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31367714/enablemongoauditing-for-mongodb-on-cloud-foundry-mongolab