# MongoDbMessageStore Could not determine IsNewStrategy Error

Tags: spring-integration, spring-data-mongodb

I'm getting the following error when I try to use the delay option on the IntegrationFlowBuilder

> Unsupported entity org.springframework.integration.mongodb.store.MongoDbMessageStore$MessageWrapper! Could not determine IsNewStrategy.

I've looked at the history of https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3346, and it seems to be related, but that issue appears to have been fixed in the version that I am using (I see the _id field).

When I step through the code, it looks as though the mapping context (and IsNewStrategy) mapped through my MongoConfig is used instead of what seems to be configured in the MongoDbMessageStore.  So, it has access to entity information for all my domain entities (those annotated with @Document), but not the MessageWrapper.

Am I missing something in my configuration?  Is there a way to force registration of the MessageWrapper entity?

**Using** 
Spring Integration - 4.2.4
Spring Data Mongo - 1.8.2

**Integration Flow**

```
IntegrationFlows.from("channel.in").delay("group1", 
     s -> s.defaultDelay(3000).messageStore(messageStore))
  .handle(<somehandler>).get()
```

**Message Store Config**

```
@Bean
public MessageGroupStore messageStore(MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory) {
    return new MongoDbMessageStore(mongoDbFactory, "messageStoreCollection")
}
```

**Mongo Config**

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoAuditing
public class MongoConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public MongoClient mongo() throws UnknownHostException {
        MongoClientOptions.Builder builder = new MongoClientOptions.build();
        MongoClientOptions options = builder.connectionsPerHost(100).build();
        return new MongoClient(new ServerAddress("localhost", 28017)), options);
    }

    protected String getDatabaseName() { return "myMongoDb"; }

    protected String getMappingBasePackage() { return "com.mycompany.myapp.entities"; }

    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate(MongoClient mongo, MongoConverter mongoConverter) throws UnknownHostException {
        return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory(), mongoConverter);
    }

    @Bean 
    public GridFstemplate gridFsTemplate() throws UnknownHostException {
        return new GridFsTemplate(mongoDbFactory(), mappingMongoConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactoryBean() {
        return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    }
}
```

**Stacktrace**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported entity org.springframework.integration.mongodb.store.MongoDbMessageStore$MessageWrapper! Could not determine IsNewStrategy.
    at org.springframework.data.support.IsNewStrategyFactorySupport.getIsNewStrategy(IsNewStrategyFactorySupport.java:48) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.auditing.IsNewAwareAuditingHandler.markAudited(IsNewAwareAuditingHandler.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.event.AuditingEventListener.onApplicationEvent(AuditingEventListener.java:54) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.event.AuditingEventListener.onApplicationEvent(AuditingEventListener.java:31) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:163) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:136) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:381) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:335) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.maybeEmitEvent(MongoTemplate.java:1627) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doInsert(MongoTemplate.java:799) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.insert(MongoTemplate.java:743) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.mongodb.store.MongoDbMessageStore.addMessageDocument(MongoDbMessageStore.java:220) ~[spring-integration-mongodb-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.mongodb.store.MongoDbMessageStore.addMessageToGroup(MongoDbMessageStore.java:302) ~[spring-integration-mongodb-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.DelayHandler.releaseMessageAfterDelay(DelayHandler.java:334) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.DelayHandler.handleRequestMessage(DelayHandler.java:267) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:99) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:147) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:120) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:442) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:392) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:231) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:154) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:102) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:105) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:147) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:120) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.channel.AbstractSubscribableAmqpChannel$DispatchingMessageListener.onMessage(AbstractSubscribableAmqpChannel.java:181) ~[spring-integration-amqp-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:800) [spring-rabbit-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:691) [spring-rabbit-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$001(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:93) [spring-rabbit-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$1.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:183) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor178.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.retry.interceptor.RetryOperationsInterceptor$1.doWithRetry(RetryOperationsInterceptor.java:74) ~[spring-retry-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:263) [spring-retry-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:168) [spring-retry-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.retry.interceptor.RetryOperationsInterceptor.invoke(RetryOperationsInterceptor.java:98) [spring-retry-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy213.invokeListener(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1358) [spring-rabbit-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:661) [spring-rabbit-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1102) [spring-rabbit-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1086) [spring-rabbit-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1100(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:93) [spring-rabbit-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1203) [spring-rabbit-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_40]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, looks like something has been changed in Spring Data MongoDB (or common).

Please, raise a [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT) on the matter and will investigate what to do.

But it looks like with the current Spring Data we won't be able to do anything from Spring Integration side.

Meanwhile consider to use `ConfigurableMongoDbMessageStore` instead and inject a `mappingMongoConverter()` with some custom `Converter` for the `Message`:

```
public static class MessageReadConverter implements Converter<DBObject, Message<?>> {

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Message<?> convert(DBObject source) {
        return MessageBuilder.withPayload(source.get("payload")).copyHeaders((Map<String, ?>) source.get("headers")).build();
    }

}

...
@Bean
public CustomConversions customConversions() {
    return new CustomConversions(Collections.singletonList(new MessageReadConverter()));
}
```

At least that is like I have with Spring Boot, where `MappingMongoConverter` is provided for me by the `MongoDataAutoConfiguration`:

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(MongoConverter.class)
public MappingMongoConverter mappingMongoConverter(MongoDbFactory factory,
        MongoMappingContext context, BeanFactory beanFactory) {
    DbRefResolver dbRefResolver = new DefaultDbRefResolver(factory);
    MappingMongoConverter mappingConverter = new MappingMongoConverter(dbRefResolver,
            context);
    try {
        mappingConverter
                .setCustomConversions(beanFactory.getBean(CustomConversions.class));
    }
    catch (NoSuchBeanDefinitionException ex) {
        // Ignore
    }
    return mappingConverter;
}
```

Comment: Also see the change into `MongoDbTests` in the Spring Integration Java DSL: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/commit/7029e299e2590d9e44b1dab4c5206f13b2b61626

Comment: I submitted a [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4082).  I'll look at implementing your suggested changes.  Thanks!

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31367714/enablemongoauditing-for-mongodb-on-cloud-foundry-mongolab